# Checking bot has permissions to send messages in a channel for discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've tried getting this to work for a few days and cannot find anything to work, the discord bot keeps crashing instead of returning.

The current permission check I'm using along with the mess of code i shouldn't need.

```
if (message.guild.members.me.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages)) {
        try {
            if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix) && !Icommand){
                message.channel.send(`Use b.help in the commands channel.`);
            }

            if (!Icommand) return;

            try {
                Icommand.execute(message, args, mention, client, PermissionsBitField);
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                message.reply('This command could not be run! The Dev has been notified.');
                
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return
        }
    } else return
```

Error as below

```
/home/pi/british-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/pi/british-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/pi/british-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (/home/pi/british-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/1001430667416064050/messages',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: 'Pong.',
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: 0,
      message_reference: { message_id: '1017162983622848512', fail_if_not_exists: true },
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Comment: can you send the error message you are getting?

Comment: If you could provide an error message from your console, that would help us in finding/fixing your issue.